# In a WPF StackPanel, why would the associated ContextMenu not show unless a Background is set?

Tags: wpf, windows

I have a WPF application which builds for both .NET 4.7 and .NET 6. In one of the views, there is a UI section like this:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding DataContext,Source={behaviors:RootObject}}">
            <MenuItem Command="{x:Static commands:MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource CommandIcon}" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
    <!--
        StackPanel Content goes here.
    -->
</StackPanel>
```

In the configuration shown above, the context menu does not appear on a right-click.

If I set a `Background` for the `StackPanel` (I.e. I change the first line to read `<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="CornflowerBlue">`), then the context menu operates as expected (including the command itself).

I have verified (using [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf)) that the context menu is set correctly, and has the expected DataContext even in the scenario where it is not appearing.

Why does setting the background make a difference? Is there a way to get the context menu to show without explicitly setting the background?

Comment: A null Background is not hit-test visible. Set Background="Transparent".

Comment: D'oh! Yeah, that would explain it. Thanks @Clemens. (I just wish that previous answer had actually shown up in my search results!)